# Obj-C category/extension Swift in Javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm looking to add methods to a class in Javascript **ES6** without creating a subclass of it, in the same way with the categories in Objective-C or extensions in Swift.

I didn't find any information about it.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Any progress here? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ES6 class syntax is simply syntax sugar over JavaScript's prototypal inheritance model. To add methods to a class, all you can do is add more properties onto the prototype.

```
class Something {

}

Something.prototype.newMethod = function(){

};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already knew this method but I was looking for a more ES6 approach for doing that. That could be a great addition to ES6 tho!

Comment: At the end of the day, you are just mixing more methods onto a prototype. I'm not quite sure what would be "more ES6" in this case. I mean, you can do `Object.assign(Something.prototype, {newMethod(){}});` if you want.

Comment: The interest of the category/extension is you can extend an existing class to an interface and implementing the new methods in the extension/category. With the method you showed above, you can't.